# Hosting WCF service in IIS

Tags: wcf, hosting, linq-to-xml, iis-5

I am trying to host  the service in IIS but I get Page Not found error.
Here is what I did to host in IIS

1. Created a WCF Service application (BillingService)
2. I have two classes called IBillSrv.cs (as Base) and BillSrvc.cs
3. Added a new WCFService website (BillSrvcSite) to the solution and added a reference to the above mentioned (BillingService).
4. In IIS created a new Virtual site and mapped it to BillSrvSite
5. Opened the Web.Config and changed the endpoint contract to IBillSrv

When I run it works fine in the WCF test client.
but when i paste the below url in IE I get page not found.
http://localhost/BillingService/BillSrvc/

I am using C# 2008
Can someone please advise what is missing or where I am going wrong?

Comment: You say, "Base Class" and "Derived Class", but you have not posted a class, only pieces of a class. Please post the smallest complete classes that reproduce this problem.

Comment: Do not delete content of your question! Now the communication between you and John doesn't make sense and nobody will bother with your question.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with persistence. An interface member like `ParseTestQues` can only be implicitly implemented by a public method. Simply make ParseTestQues be public.

---

Isn't your service endpoint named something like "BillSrvc.svc"? Try typing http://localhost/BillingService/BillSrvc/BillSrvc.svc into the browser and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you John. When I execute this program i see the ParseTestQues endpoint disabled and when i hover over i see the message "This Operation is not supported in WCF Test Client"

Comment: Did you make ParseTestQues public, like I asked? Does the project compile?

Comment: ya it compiled but i get error : "This Operation is not supported in WCF Test Client" in WCF test client

Comment: John I don't know why you have changed the title to "Don't know how to Host a WCF service".

Comment: @maadhukari: because that's the closest I could come to what you were actually asking. Can you suggest a better title for what you actually asked?